# Difference between PdfCanvas and Canvas in itext 7

Tags: java, itext7

What is the difference between the PdfCanvas and Canvas classes in the iText7 library? When should I use each one of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, `PdfCanvas` is designed for low-level operations and `Canvas` - for high-level ones.

You want to write rectangles / pathes / text and any other operators to the content stream of a pdf? Use the `PdfCanvas` instance.

You want to add high-level iText objects (`Paragraph`s, `Table`s, `List`s, ...) to your `PdfCanvas`? Use the `Canvas` instance.

**PdfCanvas example**

```
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(destinationFolder + "simpleCanvas.pdf"));

    PdfPage page1 = pdfDoc.addNewPage();

    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page1);
    canvas.rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100).fill();

    pdfDoc.close();
```

The resultant pdf: [image]

**Canvas example**

```
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(out));

    PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage();
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, rectangle);
    canvas.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));

    canvas.close();

    pdf.close();
```

The resultant pdf: [image]

Comment: I can also do `document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));`. What's the difference between `Canvas.add` and `Document.add`?

Comment: `Document` represents tha main content flow of the document. Invoking `Document#add` adds element to the current page and then shrink's the left page space, so that the next time `Document#add` is called the element to be added will be placed on a srinked area. Once there is no space on this page for the element to be added, `Document#add` creates the next page and places the element there.
`Canvas#add`, on the other hand, is designed to place content on the area around which it was construted. It shrinks this area after each `#add` as well, but doesn't create any new page in case of no space